# a specific case: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: node.js, ssl, twitter, authorization

I've been trying to do a test about TLS connection between server and client. (SSL-Client Authentication)

I have a self-signed key pair.

If I try to connect my API server using `tls.connect()`, my connection seems as `unauthorized` and `authorizationError` value is `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` as shown the below screenshot.

However, if I try to connect `https://api.twitter.com` instead of `https://hellolarim.club` then there is no error and `authorization` value is `true`. Also when I trying to Twitter I don't have to use `rejectUnauthorized: false` parameter.

I added the below `server.js`codes too.

**Question:** I'm wondering that why I cannot connect as `authorized: true` ?

I have to implement SSL-Client Authentication to my API server.

**The attempt to connect to my API server**

---

*client.js*

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-private-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-certificate.pem'),

  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

{
var cleartextStream = tls.connect(443, 'www.hellolarim.club', options, function() {

  console.log('\nclient connected', cleartextStream.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized'); 
  if(!cleartextStream.authorized) {
    console.log("authorizationError: " + cleartextStream.authorizationError);
  }

  process.stdin.resume();
  process.stdin.pipe(cleartextStream);
});
cleartextStream.setEncoding('utf8');
cleartextStream.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log("\n" + data);
});
cleartextStream.on('end', function() {
  server.close();
});
```

[image]

**The attempt to connect to Twitter API server**

---

[image]

---

*Server.js*

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true,

  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('../client/client-certificate.pem') ]
};

var server = tls.createServer(options, function(cleartextStream) {

  console.log(cleartextStream.getPeerCertificate());

  console.log('server connected',
              cleartextStream.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  cleartextStream.write("Hello from server to client!\n");
  cleartextStream.setEncoding('utf8');
  cleartextStream.pipe(cleartextStream);
});
server.listen(443, function() {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on client side.

Client cannot recognize server's certificate despite the certificate had been gotten from a commercial CA because there is no `ca` parameter on client options!

And if we have a lot of root certificates we can install them by transforming a string array like the below or use [node-ssl-root-cas](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas).

```
var CAcerts = [ 
  // A Root CA cert.
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
  "MIIF2DCCA8CgAwIBAgIQTKr5yttjb+Af907YWwOGnTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCBhTELMAkGA1UE\n" +
  "BhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgG\n" +
  "tZx8jb8uk2IntznaFxiuvTwJaP+EmzzV1gsD41eeFPfR60/IvYcjt7ZJQ3mFXLrrkguhxuhoqEwW\n" +
  "sRqZCuhTLJK7oQkYdQxlqHvLI7cawiiFwxv/0Cti76R7CZGYZ4wUAc1oBmpjIXUDgIiKboHGhfKp\n" +
  "7RH89elWsn2/x20Kk4yl0MC2Hb46TpSi125sC8KKfPog88Tk5c0NqMuRkrF8hey1FGlmDoLnzc7I\n" +
  "LaZRfyHBNVOFBkpdn627G190\n" +
  "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
  // Another Root CA cert.
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
  "MIIF2DCCA8CgAwIBAgIQTKr5yttjb+Af907YWwOGnTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCBhTELMAkGA1UE\n" +
  "BhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgG\n" +
  "tZx8jb8uk2IntznaFxiuvTwJaP+EmzzV1gsD41eeFPfR60/IvYcjt7ZJQ3mFXLrrkguhxuhoqEwW\n" +
  "sRqZCuhTLJK7oQkYdQxlqHvLI7cawiiFwxv/0Cti76R7CZGYZ4wUAc1oBmpjIXUDgIiKboHGhfKp\n" +
  "7RH89elWsn2/x20Kk4yl0MC2Hb46TpSi125sC8KKfPog88Tk5c0NqMuRkrF8hey1FGlmDoLnzc7I\n" +
  "LaZRfyHBNVOFBkpdn627G190\n" +
  "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
  ];

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-private-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-certificate.pem'),
  ca: CAcerts,
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
};
```